# How to get filename from a file "template.docx.amp" in c#?

Tags: c#

I have got a strange template whose extension is ".docx.amp" . Now i want to get fileName. i.e "template". Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension() fails as it returns template.docx. Is there any other built in mechanism or i will have to go the ugle string comparison/split way. Please suggest and give some workaround

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, you will have to use some kind of string split, eg:

```
var nameWithoutExtension = filename.Split('.')[0];
```

Comment: "string[] split(char)" is the minimal efficient solution, without needing to go into regexps' realm. +1 from me.

Comment: @Maciek but it doesn't work if the filename has a `.` in it eg: `test.file.name.docx.amp` would produce `test` instead of the propery value of `test.file.name`.

Comment: @Kelsey... In the example above it's fairly obvious what the extension is because as humans we recognise that docx is a common extension, but what about a file named "document.something.somethingelse"?  Is the non-extension part "document" or "document.something"?  Calculating the extension in the general case is non-deterministic, so I picked a method that gave the correct answer for what was asked in the original question.

Comment: I agree, but if you look on my answer he posted a comment that the extension will always be `.something.something` so you just need to get the last two parts.